# 960.gs with 100% width header

Tags: css, layout, 960.gs

Ok, I am using the 960.gs and for some design purposes I want a 100% width line with my header elements. But I can't get it to work properly without having to include multiple containers, wich I don't exactly favor.

So my question is this; how can I have a 100% width div on the top of my page, and have the content of that div follow the grid system?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I guessed this is what you want:

```
<div style="width: 100%; ...">
    <div class="container_12">
        your grid layout here
    </div>
</div>
```